# Regex pattern + preg_split keep delimiter

Tags: php, regex

I read posts about regex and preg_split but nothing fitting to my interests.

I have the following text:
C01G01 Jon Doe Kenny Ranny C02G02 Ramsay John C02G03 Alice Axel

I want to use preg_split where the delimiter is C(number)G(number) and also keep the delimiter in the array.

What I have done:

```
$parts = preg_split('/C+[0-200]+G+[0-200]/', 
$students,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

What Is returning:

```
Array(
[0] => 
[1] => 1 Jon Doe Kenny Ranny 
[2] => 2 Ramsay John 
[3] => 3 Alice Axel
)
```

What I expect to return:

```
Array(
[0] => 
[1] => C01G01 Jon Doe Kenny Ranny 
[2] => C02G02 Ramsay John 
[3] => C02G03 Alice Axel
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\s(?=C+\d+G+\d+)
```

You can use something of this sort.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qyCwCN/1

Comment: It is working perfect, thanks! 

I tried to use it with preg_replace (now I want to remove the delimiter from the array while in foreach) but seems to do not match

Comment: @Trakemys https://regex101.com/r/qyCwCN/2 ???????